# Intel VCVTTPD2QQ loads 4 numbers, not 8

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, nasm, avx512

The Intel Software Developers Manual describes VCVTTPD2QQ as:

```
Convert eight packed double-precision floating-point values
from zmm2/m512 to eight packed quadword integers in zmm1
using truncation with writemask k1.
```

I am using VCVTTPD2QQ to load eight double-precision 64-bit floats into zmm1, encoded as follows:

```
mov rax,18446744073709551615
KMOVQ k1,rax
EVEX.512.66.0F.W1 VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1 {k1}{z},[r11+r15]
```

I fill k1 with all 1's to indicate to move all 8 numbers.

If I code it this way, I still get the same result:

```
VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1 {k1}{z},[r11+r15]
```

The Intel manual distinguishes the three possible encodings by the register names; if the name is a zmm register, then it should move 8.

Why am I getting only 4 but not 8 data points loaded into zmm1?

EDIT:

I eliminated the write mask which, as Peter Cordes said below, makes no difference here.  I also created a memory array and accessed it as :

```
test_array:  dq 24.0, 93.0, 43.0, 28.0, 86.0, 143.0, 17.0, 129.0, 33.0, 67.0, 55.0

mov rdi,test_array
EVEX.512.66.0F.W1 VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1,[rdi]
```

The debugger shows the same thing as accessing the array which is read from an external file (4 elements, not 8).  Here is the gdb output:

```
(gdb) i r zmm1
zmm1 {v16_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, v8_double = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
0x0, 0x0}, v64_int8 = {0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5d, 0x0,
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
0x1c, 0x0 <repeats 39 times>}, v32_int16 = {0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5d,
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1c, 0x0 <repeats 19 times>},    v16_int32 = {0x18, 0x0, 0x5d, 0x0, 0x2b, 0x0, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,     0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, v8_int64 = {0x18, 0x5d, 0x2b, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
0x0}, v4_int128 = {0x5d0000000000000018, 0x1c000000000000002b, 0x0, 0x0}}
```

In the v8_int64 section, we see the first four values (correct) but the last four are zero and the input data are not zero.

Comment: Can you add the encoding of the instruction into hex?

Comment: How to encode it into hex?  Which part of the instruction -- the writemask?

Comment: Include a minimal, complete and verifiable example that can reproduce this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Ross Ridge - the data are read in from an external source, but I can produce an example with a memory array and see if that does it.  It will be 64-bit NASM.

Comment: @Ross Ridge - with a data array declared in the .data section the instruction does not work at all (loads only zeroes).  This instruction is specific to a data array read in from an external source.  I hoped that someone with AVX-512 experience could spot the problem.  An MCR example would need to supply external data, which is not possible (AFAIK) on SO.

Comment: The problem is in code you're not showing, and we're not psychic, so no amount of AVX-512 experience is going to help solve your problem.

Comment: I'll see what I can do for that.  I would certainly prefer to give an entire example.

Comment: Why are you using masking at all?  If you want all 8, just use unmasked.  Also, why would you write your constant in decimal, instead of `-1` or `0xffffffffffffffff` like a normal person?  Or better, `kxnorw k1, k0, k0` if you do want an all-ones mask for some reason (instead of using no masking at all).  Not that any of this would change the result, just that you're overcomplicating this.  Show the debugger output where you see "only 4" values in your ZMM register, even though the pointed-to memory had 8 non-zero `double`s.

Comment: And MCVE could be as simple as `arr: times 4 dq 3.0, 2.0` in `.rodata`, and this instruction with a memory source.

Comment: I edited my question above.  I removed the write mask as you said, and it did not make a difference.  I created a memory array and it does the same thing as the array read from external source.  But in both cases the result is the same.  I show the gdb output.  See the question above.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hmm.  GDB might be buggy here.  Try storing ZMM1 to memory and examine memory.  BTW, you can `p $zmm1.v8_int64` to just show that view of the vector reg.  Why are you including `EVEX.512.66.0F.W1` in your asm source?  That's not the problem, though; I get the same machine code from `VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1,[rdi]` as I do with that override.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that it's really only doing a 32-byte load?  e.g. does it not fault if you load the last 32 bytes before an unmapped page?  (That's highly unlikely;  it's much more likely that this is a GDB bug printing the upper 256 bits of a vector as 0 than that the instruction is actually executing wrong.)  So a better title might be that it's zeroing the top 4 elements.

Comment: Things that could be wrong: gdb display bug; you overwrote the end of the array before you loaded it into zmm1; you set a breakpoint sometime well after VCVTTPD2QQ and the instructions altered what appears to be in zmm1. At what point did you actually print zmm1? ALthough I would normally use intrinsics I decided to use inline assembly so you can see the instructions. What happens when you run this code: https://godbolt.org/z/F5dKep . And what result do you get when stopping right after VCVTTPD2QQ and getting GDB to display zmm1?

Comment: If the code at the godbolt link displays all 8 64-bit longs then the instructions did what they were suppose to. If you debug that code on your system with GDB and stop **right after** VCVTTPD2QQ and display zmm1 and it display just the 4 bottom values then it is almost certainly a GDB display bug. If it shows all 8 values then there is something else wrong in the code you have (hard to tell with no [mcve])

Comment: I know that in the past you have mixed Python and assembly, C and assembly. If this is a C and assembly project have you considered using C but using intrinsics to handle the SIMD instructions?

Comment: Mixing C and assembly is often helpful, but so far with the AVX-512 instructions I haven't had any problem in assembly (NASM).  But for an especially difficult problem, using an intrinsic could help.  Thanks for all your helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Cordes and Michael Petch both suspected in their final comments, this problem was caused by a bug in gdb.  Apparently gdb can't display the upper 256 bits of a zmm register.

The simple test, as Peter Cordes said, is to declare a test array in memory:

```
section .data
test_array2: times 8 dq 0

section .text
VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1,[r11+r15]

mov rdi,test_array2
vmovdqu64 [rdi],zmm1

mov rax,[rdi+0]
mov rax,[rdi+8]
mov rax,[rdi+16]
mov rax,[rdi+24]
mov rax,[rdi+32]
mov rax,[rdi+40]
mov rax,[rdi+48]
mov rax,[rdi+56]
```

Use gdb to step through each of the rax,[rdi+xxx] lines and see the value in rax.  In my case, all 8 values match the input data, even though gdb shows the upper 256 bits of zmm1 as zero.

If I had posted an MCR example with the original question, others may have spotted this earlier.

Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: You should consider using intrinsics rather than assembly.  A compiler would've known it could do `vmovdqu64 [test_array2], zmm1`. Also you can use the debugger to display regions of memory directly, without having to load it piece by piece into a register.